# How to update a variable in python 3.6 to that of a string of text in a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I want to update 3 variables.

X_Variable_1
X_Variable_2
X_Variable_3

(No these aren't the real names of the variables, but just for example)

Here is the text file's contents

Test
Test
True

I want X_Variable_1 to be updated to the 1st line of text, overwriting anything else on there, X_Variable_2 happening a similar way, except the second line of text in the file, and then X_Variable_3 being updated to the 3rd line of text

So in this manner, it should update them to

```
X_Variable_1 = ('Test')
X_Variable_2 = ('Test')
X_Variable_3 = (True)
```

Thanks

Comment: X_Variable_1, X_Variable_2, X_Variable_3 = 'Test', 'Test', True

Comment: `X_Variable_1= my_file.readline()` `X_Variable_2= my_file.readline()` `X_Variable_3= my_file.readline()=='True'`

Comment: Okay, I looked at Rawing's post, I tried it, so now how to I define my_file?

Comment: Sorry about this I'm a near beginner lol

Comment: Rawing assumes you already have a file open for reading. My answer doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
X_Variable_1, X_Variable_2, X_Variable_3 = open("FILENAME").readlines()
```

Or if you want the variables not to have '\n' chars at the end, do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
X_Variable_1, X_Variable_2, X_Variable_3 = [line.rstrip() for line in open("FILENAME").readlines()]
```

If you have more lines than 3, you can discard all additional lines in the file as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
X_Variable_1, X_Variable_2, X_Variable_3, *_ = [line.rstrip() for line in open("FILENAME").readlines()]
```

In all examples, set "FILENAME" to the file name you want to read, with or without the path (either relative or absolute).

Comment: Alright, the ball may be rolling with this. It tells me that the file I want it to read from doesn't exist, so how would I point it to know where the file it needs to read from is? (also, it'd need to read from where the .py file that is launched is, not just a static area)

Comment: I edited the post - change "FILENAME" to your file's name, with or without the path. If you just put the filename without a path, it will read from where your .py file is.

Comment: Correction - it will read from your current working directory - if you are working in the folder your .py file is, that will be the same. If not (if you plan to put your .py file in some folder on your $PATH and run it from different places), that code is slightly different.